# Counting and multiple grouping in many-to-many MySQL table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, grouping, counting

I'm wondering all day and I cant get it done.

I have a simple test table with `news` system as example. We have `news`, `tags`, and `categories`.
`News` can have many `tags` and one `category`. What I need is to count how many `news` are under each `tag` in each `category`. For example we could have 4 `news` with general tag under politics category and 2 `news` with general tag under science category.

My tables looks like this:

```
news:
    - news_id
    - category_id
    - title

categories:
    - category_id
    - category_name

tags:
    - tag_id
    - tag_name

news_tags:
    - news_id
    - tag_id
```

Here is a simple MindMap to clarify what I need:
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ySiJ.png

Here is a query I've tried with no success:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(n.news_id) AS news_count FROM news AS n
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON n.category_id = c.category_id
LEFT JOIN news_tags AS tn ON n.news_id = tn.news_id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON tn.tag_id = t.tag_id
GROUP BY t.tag_id, c.category_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query works without errors for me.
What error do you get when you run your query/Why is it no success?

This is my attempt to set up your situation:

```
mysql> select * from news;
+---------+-------------+------------------------+
| news_id | category_ID | title                  |
+---------+-------------+------------------------+
|       1 |           1 | politics and general 1 |
|       2 |           1 | politics and general 2 |
|       3 |           1 | politics and general 3 |
|       4 |           1 | politics and general 4 |
|       5 |           2 | science and general 1  |
|       6 |           2 | science and general 2  |
|       7 |           2 | science and funny 1    |
+---------+-------------+------------------------+

mysql> select * from tags;
+--------+----------+
| tag_id | tag_name |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | general  |
|      2 | funny    |
+--------+----------+

mysql> select * from news_tags;
+---------+--------+
| news_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |
|       2 |      1 |
|       3 |      1 |
|       4 |      1 |
|       5 |      1 |
|       6 |      1 |
|       7 |      2 |
+---------+--------+

mysql> select * from categories;
+-------------+---------------+
| category_id | category_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|           1 | politics      |
|           2 | science       |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Result of your query:

```
+---------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------+--------+--------+----------+------------+
| news_id | category_ID | title                  | category_id | category_name | news_id | tag_id | tag_id | tag_name | news_count |
+---------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------+--------+--------+----------+------------+
|       1 |           1 | politics and general 1 |           1 | politics      |       1 |      1 |      1 | general  |          4 |
|       5 |           2 | science and general 1  |           2 | science       |       5 |      1 |      1 | general  |          2 |
|       7 |           2 | science and funny 1    |           2 | science       |       7 |      2 |      2 | funny    |          1 |
+---------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------+--------+--------+----------+------------+
```

However it doesn't make sense to `SELECT *` since you're aggregating counts by tag/category and things like `title` don't make sense when aggregated.

You might try:

```
SELECT c.category_name, t.tag_name, COUNT(n.news_id) AS news_count FROM news AS n
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON n.category_id = c.category_id
LEFT JOIN news_tags AS tn ON n.news_id = tn.news_id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON tn.tag_id = t.tag_id
GROUP BY t.tag_id, c.category_id;
```

To get:

```
+---------------+----------+------------+
| category_name | tag_name | news_count |
+---------------+----------+------------+
| politics      | general  |          4 |
| science       | general  |          2 |
| science       | funny    |          1 |
+---------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: side note: I only just discovere the `block quote` thingy on the stackoverflow edit toolbar when you write a post....I just spent forever adding 4 spaces to the front of everything manually! d'oh!

Comment: Well... I don't get any error with my query, it works, but I thought I was getting bad results. Now I spotted that I actually got right results, but because of selecting ALL data (just for test purposes) my eyes didn't saw this and I've counted something bad. Well, sorry for this and thanks for making this clear to me.